# Proving infimum

Tags: limits, induction

I have to prove:

> If $x_n=\frac{3n-1}{n},\ x\in\Bbb{R},n \in \Bbb{N}$, then  $\displaystyle\inf_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\{x_n\}=3$.

First I have to prove by induction the sequence is growing, but then i got this and I'm stuck:

$\frac{3n+2}{n+1}>\frac{3n-1}{n}$
not sure what to do next.

Comment: I altered the layout, because your original was a bit ambiguous. Is the question still what you want to ask?

Comment: I'm not sure this statement is true. The infimum must be a lower bound, but $3$ is not a lower bound for this sequence. Perhaps you want to prove that $3$ is the supremum, not the infimum.

Comment: Note that $\frac{3n-1}{n}\leq\frac{3n}{n}=3$.

Comment: Sure, so $3$ is an upper bound. Whereas the infimum is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: Check if this is correctly stated, since it isn't true as it stands. For $n = 1$ then $(3n - 1)/n = 2$

Comment: The sequence $(x_n)= 3-1/n$  is not bounded below by 3 though, so 3 cannot be the inf.

Comment: Maybe it should be $\liminf$.

Comment: Induction is not the right tool to prove the sequence is increasing. We want to show that $\frac{3n+2}{n+1}\gt \frac{3n-1}{n}$, or equivalently that $\frac{3n+2}{n+1}-\frac{3n-1}{n}\gt 0$. Bring the expression $\frac{3n+2}{n+1}-\frac{3n-1}{n}$ to a common denominator, simplify the top and I think things will be clear. There are easier ways, for our expression is $3-\frac{1}{n}$, and $\frac{1}{n}$ is decreasing, so $3-\frac{1}{n}$ is increasing.

Comment: The sequence converges, so the $\liminf$ is equal to the limit, which is 3.

Comment: As some of you suggested, the question was incorrectly stated. I won't repost it since, now I can solve it. Should I delete the question? @PatrickStevens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof that $3$ is indeed the supremum, not the infimum:

To prove that the sequence is increasing, consider, it is always true that $$3n^2 + 2n > 3n^2 + 2n -1$$ but we can re-write this inequality as $$(3n + 2)n > (3n-1)(n+1)$$ then cross divide to get $$\frac{3n+2}{n+1} > \frac{3n-1}{n}.$$ Thus the sequence is increasing. The sequence is also bounded above by $3$. Indeed $$\frac{3n-1}{n} \le \frac{3n}{n} = 3.$$ An increasing sequence which is bounded above converges to its supremum. Thus to find the supremum, we simply need to take the limit. We see $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3n-1}{n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} 3 - \frac{1}{n} = 3.$$ Thus $3$ is the supremum of the sequence.  Alternatively, you could argue by definition. We showed above that $3$ is an upper bound. To prove it is the least upper bound, we need to show that $3 - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for any $\epsilon > 0$. Indeed, if $\epsilon > 0$, then there is $N \in \mathbb N$ with $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$. But then $-\frac{1}{N} > - \epsilon$ so $$3-\frac{1}{n} > 3 - \epsilon \,\,\, \Longleftrightarrow \,\,\, \frac{3n-1}{n} > 3-\epsilon.$$ Thus $3-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound for the sequence, so $3$ is the least upper bound, i.e., 3 is the supremum.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
However those who argued that  it is not correctly stated are correct.
The real question was:
$x=\frac{3n+1}{n}$

Comment: In that case, follow these exact same arguments, just flip signs and inequalities.